# How can I get rid of NA values on data import in R?

Tags: r

Follow up to this post:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/importing-csv-gets-me-all-16-000-columns-with-quot-NA-quot-td3006480.html

Some background: I am developing a program that allows the user to upload csv files. Currently, I am testing a dataset that looks like:

```
Type    Date    Lively  Count
sm  1/13/2010   10  10
sm  1/14/2010   10  20
sm  2/15/2010   20  30
am  4/16/2010   5   42
am  1/17/2010   10  34
am  3/18/2010   40  54
sm  1/19/2010   10  65
sm  4/20/2010   5   67
sm  3/21/2010   40  76
sm  3/21/2010   70  76
```

When the user imports this, everything is fine. My import method is:

```
dataset <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)
dataset <- na.omit(dataset)
```

However, let's say the user saved the above table in Excel, saving it as a csv. Then he deleted the last two columns.

```
Type    Date    
sm  1/13/2010   
sm  1/14/2010       
sm  2/15/2010   
am  4/16/2010   
am  1/17/2010   
am  3/18/2010   
sm  1/19/2010   
sm  4/20/2010   
sm  3/21/2010   
sm  3/21/2010
```

If I looked at the str() of this table, the last 2 columns wold now contain NA values because in Excel, the columns have already been formatted. I can't take in these NA values, as they mess up my program later on. I'd like to get rid of them. My na.omit() doesn't seem to do anything about the NAs.

I have found a solution using

```
dataset[is.na(dataset)] <- c("")
```

to replace these columns with blank chars, but this could mess me up later when I'm checking which columns of the uploaded dataset are characters!

Does anyone have a better solution (telling the user to upload the file in another Excel sheet is not an option )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove columns containing only `NA`:

```
dataset [,colSums(is.na(dataset )) <nrow(dataset),drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Oooh, very nice, thank you very much sir. Just a small syntax issue: nrow(dataset) instead of nrow(dat)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution to remove all columns that have only missing values,

```
dataset[,sapply(dataset, function(x)!all(is.na(x)))]
```